# ios growing two controls with CGAffineTransformMakeScale doesn't keep center correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to animate a label and an image view, have them growth from nothing to the size and position I have them in interface builder.

My image view is bigger that the label and the label sits inside it, at the top.
like so...

```
.............................
.                           .
. ......................... .
. .                       . .
. .        LABEL          . .
. .                       . .
. ......................... .
.                           .
.      IMAGE VIEW           .
.............................
```

I think the center point where the animation should start from would be center of the label.

Here's what I've tried, I may want to add further animations, hence the array.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.imv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.0);
    self.lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.0);

    NSMutableArray* animationBlocks = [NSMutableArray new];
    typedef void(^animationBlock)(BOOL);
    animationBlock (^getNextAnimation)() = ^{
        animationBlock block = animationBlocks.count ? 
             (animationBlock)[animationBlocks objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
        if (block){
            [animationBlocks removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            return block;
        }else{
            return ^(BOOL finished){};
        }
    };

    [animationBlocks addObject:^(BOOL finished){;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            //grow
            self.lbl.hidden = NO;
            self.lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
            self.imv.hidden = NO;
            self.imv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);

        } completion: getNextAnimation()];
    }];

    [animationBlocks addObject:^(BOOL finished){;
        //
    }];
    getNextAnimation()(YES);
 }
```

I've tried setting the anchor point and I've also looked at CGAffineTransformScale, but I'm not sure what will work in the situation / confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to combine the scale transformation with a translation. something like

```
CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0,0), self.imv.frame.size.width/2 , self.imv.frame.size.height/2);
```

Comment: But do it for both the label and the image view ?

Comment: It just works separated, so If you do it for both, each one will scale from its center. If you want both scale at once, you need them to be subviews of the same parent view and scale this (easy option). or you have to calculate the needed center to apply for the translation (a bit more work)

Comment: things get simpler of course, if your label is added as subview of the imageView. then you only need to scale the imageView.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the animation doesn't happen now.

Comment: Ok, I added it as a subview :)